# Display firstname and lastname of the employees with highest and lowest salary with respect to jobroles

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have these tables with the following columns :

```
Employee24( EMPLOYEEID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, GENDER, JOBROLES);

Salary25( EMPLOYEEID, SALARYID, JOBROLES, BASICSAL, ALLOWANCES);
```

Display firstname and lastname of the employees with highest and lowest salary with respect to jobroles

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMPLOYEE24 
WHERE EMPLOYEEID IN (SELECT EMPLOYEEID, JOBROLES FROM SALARY25 GROUP BY JOBROLES));
```

Comment: Please also include sample data and expected results for that data in your question.

Answer (score 1):

This query gets the employee ids.  I'll let you figure out how to get the names:

```
select s.employeeid
from (select s.*, min(basicsal) over (partition by jobrole) as min_bs, 
             max(basicsal) over (partition by jobrole) as max_bs
      from salary25 s
     ) s
where basicsal in (min_bs, max_bs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the `JOIN` with `Salary25` table and do the *aggregation* :

```
select e.firstname, e.lastname, 
       s.HighestSal, s.LowestSal, e.jobroles
from Employee24 e inner join 
     (select employeeid, max(basicsal) as HighestSal, min(basicsal) as LowestSal
      from salary25 
      group by jobrole
     ) s 
     on s.jobrole = e.jobrole;
```

However, the preceding query calculated salary based on `BASICSAL` and you might need `ALLOWANCES` also. So, you can change the formula accordingly.